# Django ModelChoiceField - use something other than id?

Tags: python, django, validation, django-forms, django-validation

Say I have an `address` table and it has a `postal_code` field -- ModelChoiceField does not allow me to use something other than PKs to validate existence correct? What would be the way to go? Normal input and use `clean_*()`?

Comment: Depends on how the relation ship is set up, by default its with the `primary_key` of `postal_code` model. Can you give more details like your `address` and the related `postal_code` models. A `ModelChoiceField` by default creates a dropdown with options as existing instances of the related model.

Answer (score 26):

What about `to_field_name`? [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.to_field_name). You can also find it easily between `ModelChoiceField` constructor params: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py. It is used to filter field queryset.

For example:

```
articles = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Articles.objects.all(),
        to_field_name='slug')
```

Comment: Beware, in 1.4 (haven't tried 1.5 yet, sorry) it's broken when used with `instance` argument, as `model_to_dict` forcibly uses PK (actually, `value_for_object`). To work around one has to do `YourForm(..., instance=foo, initial={"bar": foo.bar.slug})`. See `BaseModelForm.__init__` implementation for details.

Comment: In a meanwhile Django devs are working on proper fix, I'm using [this quick-and-dirty monkey patch to make `to_field_name` work](https://gist.github.com/drdaeman/5326761). Just thought I'd share it, even though it's a hack.

Comment: Hi guys, anyone have problems recently using slug instead of id for ModelChoiceField and ChoiceField? or the bug mentioned by @drdaeman is now fixed? I'm using Django 1.5.5 btw and so far I haven't experienced any issues.

Comment: Works fine with Django-1.7.1

Answer (score 1):

ModelChoiceFields are meant to be used to select between a choice of existing model instances.    This is almost always best represented by some form of Select field.

That said do you really have a FK from address to postal_code as you're implying.  What are you storing on a PostalCode table to justify the extra table that will need to be joined in for every address related query?

For most cases postal_code should simply be a CharField and in that case if you want to validate that the value is valid you can use the `choices` attribute with a list of valid postal codes.  Keep in mind that maintaining a list of valid postal codes by hand is a huge hassle.

If you really have a PostalCode table and think it's a good idea (which in some cases it could be) you may want to consider actually using the postal_code as the primary key rather than the default autoincrement since it's necessarily unique, makes your data more exportable, and solves your issue with validation.

Answer (score 1):

If `postal_code` is a foreign key to a PostalCode model that contains valid postal codes I would just use use a CharField and then do a clean like you suggested. My clean method would look like this:

```
def clean_postal_code(self):
    try:
        code = PostalCode.objects.get(code_field=self.data['postal_code'])
    except:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Please enter a valid postal code")
    return code
```